Is there a lightweight way to define a mutable dictionary that can return all of its keys in Coq?
I want to define a mutable dictionary that can return all of its keys in its domain. Keys don't have to be ordered. I searched in the coq library doc on the internet and didn't seem to find anything useful for this purpose. I don't want to write it as a list of pairs because it feels too ad hoc. Is there a standard way to do this?
As an example, how can I define a dictionary d := {a -> 1; b -> 2; c -> 3}, and a function "keys", such that keys d = [a; b; c]?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I also want to use datatypes that I defined myself as keys. For example something like:
Inductive a := cons_a : string -> a.
Inductive b := cons_b : string -> b.
Inductive c :=
  | cons_c : int -> cons_c
  | c1
  | c2.
Inductive d :=
  | cons_d1 : string -> d
  | cons_d2 : string -> d

and I want to define a map for each of a b c d as keys. Like d1 := {cons_a "a" -> 1; cons_a "b" -> 2}, d2 := {cons_d1 "a" -> 1; cons_d2 "a" -> 2}, d3 := {cons_c 1 -> 1; c1 -> 0}, etc.

The standard library Coq.FSets.FMapxxx is what you are looking for (although there are many equivalents out there). First find the functor corresponding to the maps you want (here I take FMapAVL), and instantiate it with an OrderedType for keys (here I take the already defined OrderedTypeEx.String_as_OT). Note the type of elements is left quantified:
Require FSets.FMapInterface FSets FMapAVL.
Module Import FMapInt := FMapAVL.Make(OrderedTypeEx.String_as_OT).

(* Let us define a map string -> t *)
Require Import String.
Open Scope string_scope.

Definition foo:= (add "a" 1 (add "b" 2 (add "c" 3 (empty _)))).

(* this gives the list of pairs (key,val) *)
Eval compute in elements foo.

(* A simple map gives the list of keys. With AVL this list
   is ordered, but it is not necessary the case with other
   kinds of maps. *)
Eval compute in (List.map fst (elements foo)).

(* see the list of lemmas about FMapInt: *)
Search FMapInt.t .


Just to clarify, the different "FMapxxx" functors are the different implementations for maps, and you chose AVL because it's efficient? Also I want to use some inductive data types that I defined myself as keys. How would that work?

Yes that's it: you chose one implementation. To use your own kind of keys you would need to define your own OrderedType module and apply the functor Make on it.

stdpp has gmap, which has a dom function (returning a gset) and that has a to_list function. These compute reasonably well for concrete instances, but in general they work by de- and re-encoding keys into numbers, which might not be what you want.
See https://plv.mpi-sws.org/coqdoc/stdpp/stdpp.gmap.html.
